# Поиск введённого слова в массиве C++

Tags: c++, консоль, find

Что мне нужно сделать чтобы произошел поиск введённого пользователем слова в массиве типа `string`?
Пытаюсь сделать магазин в виде консольного приложения, где пользователь выбирает товар из списка, а затем программа запрашивает количество выбранного товара. И так до тех пор, пока пользователь не закончит выбор товаров и выставления ему итоговой суммы всего списка покупок.